# mongoid embeds_many as with concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mongoid

I'm trying to build a model for annotations like the one App.net has: http://developers.app.net/docs/meta/annotations/. To easily add the annotations to many models I use a concern.

So far I have the model for the Annotation:

```ruby
class Annotation
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :key, :type => String
  field :value

  embedded_in :annotatable, polymorphic: true

  # Some validations

  attr_accessible :key, :value
  attr_accessor :key, :value
end
```

The concern:

```ruby
module Annotatable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    embeds_many :annotations, as: :annotatable
  end

  # Somewhat helper method to add annotaion only after they are valid.
  def add_annotation( annotation )

    if !annotation.valid?
      return false
    else
      self.annotations.push annotation
      return true      
    end

  end

end
```

And finally there's a model where I include the concern:

```ruby
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  include Annotatable

  # Much other stuff...

end
```

Unfortunately the annotations won't get saved :-/
Any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide how are you saving the object?